# UWP FullTrust DotNetCore

Tags: xaml, uwp, .net-core, desktop-bridge

Having issues getting a dotnetcore2.1 console app running as part of a UWP package with full trust launcher, code:

```
<Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" 
        Executable="NBXplorer\NBXplorer.exe">
        <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="Parameters" Parameters="/--datadir 
        nbxplorer /--chains btc /--network testnet" />
      </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
  </desktop:Extension>
</Extensions>

if(ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent
("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
{
    await 
    FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync
    ("Parameters");
}
```

The DotNetCore console launches, spits out the following console log: 
    Specify --help for a list of available options and commands net core

then the process is killed.... really don't get it when this DotNetCore app launched fine standalone

Hierarchy structuor for the DotNetCore app and dll dependencies is: UWPAppPackage->NBXplorer->Files

Really need help with this , I cannot afford to wait till end of year when MSFT releases a working fullTrust with DotNetCore3.0!

Comment: @IvanIčin either I did not word it the best or you misinterpreted it. Full Trust Process and dotNetCore exist now and the app is DotBetCore2.1 compatible, I mentioned 3.0 because I read VS2019 will have better compatibility with DotNetCore3.0 but we don't know if this is the culprit yet, hence the posting. Either way your comment is not constructive.

Comment: @Stefan Wick MSFT, Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters should NOT start with a '/ ', at least not for .NETCore apps, as depicted in the fullTrustLauncher examples of:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/

this is misleading